# Question about Google Analytics for Google Code page

Tags: open-source, google-analytics, google-code, project-hosting

I have an open source project hosted on Google Code and I recently added Google analytics to the Code Page, but I'm noticing that none of the file downloads are tracked.

It might be because the code page is in the http://code.google.com/p/[project name] domain and the downloads are in the http://[project name].googlecode.com/files/[file name] domain, but I don't know how to add that domain to be analysed.

Does anyone know what to do to get the downloads from the Downloads tab of a Google Code Project to be tracked by Google Analytics?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Downloads should be automatically tracked but they are tracked as events, not as page views.

See [DownloadsFAQ](http://code.google.com/p/support/wiki/DownloadsFAQ#Can_Google_Analytics_be_used_to_track_downloads?).